# Cannot require mongo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am having a really wierd situation. I want to install the [mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) gem. So I follow the instructionns, adding this to my Gemfile.

> gem 'mongo', '~> 2.4'

This is the typical approach and has worked in all other cases. When I try `require 'mongo'` from rails console, though, I get an error:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mongo

I did run `bundle install`. I have no idea what's differennt between this gem and my other gems that's causing it not to work. We are using Rails 4. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same gemset where you installed the gem?

Comment: @Bustikiller I'm using rbenv not gemsets. but it's been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by running `spring stop`.